# Add calculated column at the end of command result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to get a list with those fields in just a command:

```
IP[TAB]MAC[TAB]VENDOR[TAB]HOSTNAME
```

This is the result that I'd like to have:

```
192.168.1.1[TAB]54:a0:50:xx:xx:xx[TAB]ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.[TAB]Router
192.168.1.2[TAB]60:33:4b:xx:xx:xx[TAB]Apple, Inc.[TAB]iMac-John
192.168.1.52[TAB]08:ed:b9:xx:xx:xx[TAB]Apple, Inc.[TAB]iMac-Peter
192.168.1.26[TAB]c0:11:73:xx:xx:xx[TAB]Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd[TAB]Erik's Android
```

I can get the three first columns easily with this command:

```
sudo arp-scan -l | tail -n +3 | head -n -3
```

Result:

```
192.168.1.1[TAB]54:a0:50:xx:xx:xx[TAB]ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
192.168.1.2[TAB]60:33:4b:xx:xx:xx[TAB]Apple, Inc.
192.168.1.52[TAB]08:ed:b9:xx:xx:xx[TAB]Apple, Inc.
192.168.1.26[TAB]c0:11:73:xx:xx:xx[TAB]Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
```

The problem is to add the 4th column, I'm trying to do it with `awk` command but I get the result in a new line instead of the format I like.

```
sudo arp-scan -l | tail -n +3 | head -n -3 | awk -F '\t' '{ print $0 system("getent hosts " $1) }'
```

Unexpected result:

```
192.168.1.1[TAB]Router
192.168.1.1[TAB]54:a0:50:xx:xx:xx[TAB]ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
192.168.1.2[TAB]iMac-John
192.168.1.2[TAB]60:33:4b:xx:xx:xx[TAB]Apple, Inc.
192.168.1.52[TAB]iMac-Peter
192.168.1.52[TAB]08:ed:b9:xx:xx:xx[TAB]Apple, Inc.
192.168.1.26[TAB]Erik's Android
192.168.1.26[TAB]c0:11:73:xx:xx:xx[TAB]Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (the output of sudo arp-scan -l) and expected output.

Comment: Presumably the IP address is the common key. Investigate the `join` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for your current awk command is:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    cmd="getent hosts \"" $1 "\""
    $0 = $0 OFS ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A" )
}1'
```

but you definitely don't need the `tail` since you could just do `NR>2{...}` in awk and there's a good chance you don't need the `head` either but without seeing the raw `arp-scan` output we can only guess.

Also - if this is all you're doing with awk then you should probably be using shell instead:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r ip rest; do
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$ip" "$rest" $(getent hosts "$ip")
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I detected that the lines with the HOSTNAME at the end the separator isn't a [TAB] but the lines with N/A it's a [TAB] how can I fix that?

Comment: You're welcome but that is not possible. The tab is being produced by the `FS` that sits BEFORE the ternary expression so the tab IS present no matter whether a hostname or N/A follows it. Whether the script is doing `print $0 "\t" hostname` or `print $0 "\t" "N/A"` the output starts with `$0 "\t"` either way. That `FS` should really be a `OFS` btw so I'm about to update the answer but that's just a cosmetic change and makes absolutely zero difference functionally since both variables have the value `\t`.